# Replacement for UIView's contentStretch?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios6, deprecated, stretching

In iOS 6.0 the contentStretch property of UIView was deprecated.
How can I achieve the same functionality with new/old/other API?

The functionality I am looking for is stretching just part of an image (everything but the edges) on a UIButton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use resizableImageWithCapInsets and UIEdgeInsets to make a stretching UIButton background image. For example:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

I don't think you can stretch more than one pixel both horizontal and vertical.

Hope this helps.