# replacement for UIView's contentStretch for non-image-based content

Tags: ios, uiview, stretching

I have a UIView subclass.  It is drawing some things based on a lot of complicated code that I would greatly prefer not to disturb for this particular purpose.

I am using the now-deprecated contentStretch property to make certain changes to my view.  Apple's documentation suggests a replacement for image-based content -- see here: [Replacement for UIView's contentStretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663721/replacement-for-uiviews-contentstretch).  But it is silent on the question of what to do if the content is not image-based.

Any suggestions?  In one particular case, it is for an animation.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question yet? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Anyone ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a true replacement, but for those that need it for an animation, to animate from one size to another, a solution could be to take a [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18631340/4815066), obtain an image, use the UIImageView [stretch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667521/4815066) functions and animate to this image.