# 'contentStretch' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my code when i type in

```
    textViewBackgroundImage.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
```

it shows its been deprecated, Can someone help me in finding me the replacement for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for UIView's contentStretch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663721/replacement-for-uiviews-contentstretch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic) CGRect contentStretch   NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0,6_0);
```

// animatable. default is unit rectangle {{0,0} {1,1}}. Now deprecated: please use

```
 -[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:] to achieve the same effect.

 UIImage* cardImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"card_resizable.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(72, 0, 60, 0)];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:

Comment: If you were using contentStretch, you probably want to use -[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets: resizingMode:] and choose the 'stretch' mode.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming textViewBackgroundImage is an UIImageView,

```
[textViewBackgroundImage.image resizableImageWithCapInsets:
                                        UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)];
```

So, in place of 'CGRectMake', now we should use 'UIEdgeInsetsMake', and rather than using the 'contentStretch' property, we should use the 'resizableImageWithCapInsets' method. According to apple, the effect will be same.